# Como recuperar elementos de outra tabela numa consulta SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Peguei dados de uma tabela ***wp_posts*** e agora preciso pegar dados da tabela ***wp_postmeta*** que coincidem com o ***ID*** capturado na tabela ***wp_posts***. Estes dados são as ***product_img1***, ***product_img2***, ***product_img3*** conforme mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O SQL que usei para capturar as informações do ***wp_posts*** é este:

```
<?php

    require("configs/conxao.php");
    $conectado = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'wpcproduct'");
    $conectado->execute();

    while($produtos = $conectado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        echo $produtos["ID"]."<br>";                                
        echo $produtos["post_title"]."<br>";

    }

?>
```

Podem me ajudar a terminar esta SQL?

Comment: http://imasters.com.br/artigo/240/sql-server/entendendo-joins/

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Comment: Não entendi sua edição, você incorporou a resposta na pergunta? Com isso, invalidou a resposta que foi dada. Se tem dúvidas sobre o que a resposta sugere, use os comentários abaixo dela. Vou reverter a edição.

Comment: Poderia conectar diretamente ao WP e usar funções nativas.

Comment: Pode me ajudar nisso @Brasofilo?

Comment: E, na verdade verdade, o melhor é você dizer qual problema está tentando resolver, não simplesmente o problema que tem com o código. Assim, dá pra responder com precisão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce não passou o layout das tabelas, mas acredito que ambas possuem uma chave primaria, o que irá fazer a ligação entre ambas ( o que chamamos de join ).

Seu select ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
select p.*, pm.*  
from wp_posts p  
join wp_postmeta pm on p.post_id = pm.meta_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'wpcproduct'
```

Comment: Colei o código da outra resposta aqui. Você sempre deve [edit] suas postagens para corrigir erros, em vez de postar novamente ok?

Comment: Hein @rcaratchuk pode me mostrar como recuperar os dados da tabela `wp_postmeta` dentro do `while` por favor?

Comment: Marcos, eu sou DBA , nâo desenvolvedor PHP.estou tentando entender qual o seu problema , para contribuir no forum,  por gentileza seja mais claro em sua dúvida.